# Converting WebService into DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, dll

I have one windows service project. I want to convert that web service project into DLL. As a class library I can simply reuse those methods just by referencing that DLL.

I just want to know is there any simple way to do it or I have to manually create one class library project and reuse my code.

Comment: There isn't really a magic way of doing it; at least if you move the code yourself, then you'll also be able to separate out any of the code that deals with web service, HTTP etc versus the code you want to put in the class libray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and asking questions on ASP forums proper way of doing this is to manually reuse code.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference exe in other projects same as dll. 
But moving this to separate class library is the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just Click on the class library with the service code and select build. it will create a DLL file in your Debug folder in your project bin directory. You can use that DLL file anywhere.Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your code to class library project and built it. It will create .dll and you can easly use it by adding reference to your project. I think that would be a simplest approach